# rspec capybara error - undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, rspec2

I have:

- Have added `gem 'capybara'` to my `Gemfile` and I have run `bundle`
- Have placed my spec in spec/requests as `visit_home_page_root_spec.rb`
- Have added to `spec/spec_helper.rb:

-

```
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

but I still get the message shown in the title.

My spec is:

```
describe "Home Page", :type => :feature do

  it "Visit the home page" do
    visit '/'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Linker'
  end

end
```

`Gemfile.lock` has:

```
rspec-core (2.14.8)
rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
rspec-mocks (2.14.6)
rspec-rails (2.14.1)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activemodel (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  railties (>= 3.0)
  rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
```

Comment: yes: gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0" which is rspec 3.x I believe

Comment: It shouldn't be - what's the actual version that is resolving to (check Gemfile.lock if you are using bundler)

Comment: Add the rspec info from my Gemfile.lock

Comment: My Gemfile has `gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0"`  Maybe I should remove the 2.0 versioning and try running them.

Comment: I tried that and did bundle install and then running the test and I get the same error.

Comment: I also tried moving the file to /features and running it there but same result.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the capybara DSL isn't being included in your example. This has been done automatically less and less (and not at all in rspec 3) but from memory it should be your versions.

Nevertheless, you should be able to remedy this by doing

```
describe "foo" do
  include Capybara::DSL
end
```

For any specs that need it. Alternatively, in your `RSpec.configure` block, doing

```
config.include(Capybara::DSL, :type => :feature)
```

Would do that automatically for all specs of type feature)

Comment: Please note that the `type` option no longer (since RSpec 3) 'magically' applies the configuration option to tests in `spec/features` - see http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#filetype_inference_disabled_by_default for more details.